# npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, renD:\E-commerceJs\frontend\node_modules\.axios.DELETE'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, axios

I am building my e-commerce using vanilla js and webpack with npm but I keep gettin this error when I try installing axios.

`npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\E-commerceJs\frontend\node_modules\axios' -> 'D:\E-commerceJs\frontend\node_modules\.axios.DELETE'`

I have deleted my package.lock.json and node modules and reinstalled. I have also tried manually adding the axios dependency in the package.json file below but nothing is working.

`dependencies: { "axios": "^0.21.1" }`

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

So after a long search. I tried `npm i axios -S` and this worked for me. Hope it helps anyone else with this problem.